# Getting stored procedure final call from C# using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataadapter

I'm using a `SqlDataAdapter` to call a stored procedure. I'd like to get the final SQL that's produced but I can't seem to find it.

```
da.UpdateCommand.CommandText;
```

returns just the stored procedure name.

And

```
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters[0].Parametername.ToString();
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
```

returns the name and value, but I'd have to put them together into a string and even see which values are strings and put them in quotes myself. There are 51 parameters for this stored procedure alone.

So is there a way I can get the final call that gets sent to SQL that has the stored procedure name and all the parameters put together?

Comment: The point is : the call is ***NOT*** going to replace the "parameter" placeholders with their values. The call is made with the stored procedure name, including all defined parameter placeholders - and the values are sent separately to SQL Server. The SQL Server client library never concatenates together the call with the actual values! So what you seem to be after just will not be possible - since that's not the way it's done.